# Selenium Webdriver - unable to select an option from the list box

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select an option Pune(PNQ) from "Leaving from" list box of this page
http://book.spicejet.com/

```
driver.get("http://book.spicejet.com");
Thread.sleep(50000);
Select S = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ControlGroupSearchView_AvailabilitySearchInputSearchVieworiginStation1")));
S.selectByValue("PNQ");
```

But I am receiving this error:

> org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException

I am new to Selenium. Please help.

Comment: The ID you are searching for is not visible on the page.  You can try replacing the id in your Select with this: ControlGroupSearchView_AvailabilitySearchInputSearchVieworiginStation1_CTXT - although I'm not certain that would actually fix the issue.  That HTML is set up like a select, but I'm not entirely sure it's a select as recognized by Selenium.

Comment: If you're new to selenium, check out this framework. http://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium it's a pretty baked framework for getting started with selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight from the Selenium source -

```
/**
 * Thrown to indicate that although an element is present on the DOM, it is not visible, and so is
 * not able to be interacted with.
 */
public class ElementNotVisibleException...
```

As it says, the element is there on the DOM, but not visible to operate with.  If there a preemptive action you have to take before that element exists, then do that.

An example would be Google image searches.  When you click on an image, a black box appears with the picture. That element is always there, but you have to `click` on an image to make it appear.

Sounds like the same thing is happening with your select box.

#### Edit

I took the liberty of further looking at your particular issue.. it looks like that site hides that `<select>` tag because it's filled in by some jQuery stuff.

Instead of using the select tag and selecting by value, do,

```
driver.findElement(By.id("ControlGroupSearchView_AvailabilitySearchInputSearchVieworiginStation1_CTXT").sendKeys("PNQ");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[value='PNQ']").click();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: As per my understanding.. you are first giving some input to the jQuery then the options are getting visible, so then you are selecting the option PNQ. Is my understanding correct.

Comment: jQuery is monitoring that input field, and as you type, the layer appears filters by that text

Comment: If this answer answers your question, and you are no longer having this issue, go ahead and accept this answer by clicking the Green check mark so this question can be closed